# On the sign of a certain derivative for large $x$

Tags: calculus

**QUESTION**

> What is the sign of $$\frac{d}{dx} \bigg(\frac{x+1}{x}+\bigg(\frac{2x}{x+1}\bigg)^{\dfrac{\ln(6/5)}{\ln(31/25)}}\bigg)$$ when $x > {10}^{500}$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx%20%28%28x%2B1%29%2Fx%20%2B%20%282x%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%5E%28ln%286%2F5%29%2Fln%2831%2F25%29%29%29) gives
$$
\begin{split}
p(x)
 &= \frac{d}{dx}
    \left(\frac{x+1}{x}
        + \left(\frac{2x}{x+1}\right)^{\dfrac{\ln(6/5)}{\ln(31/25)}}\right) \\
 &= -\frac{x+1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x}
  + \frac{\left(\frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{x}{(x+1)^2}\right)
          2^{\dfrac{\ln(6/5)}{\ln(31/25)}}
          \ln(\frac{6}{5})
          \left(\frac{x}{x+1}\right)^{\dfrac{\ln(6/5)}{\ln(31/25)} - 1}}
         {\ln(\frac{31}{25})}.
\end{split}
$$

Solving for the root(s) of $p(x)=0$ (again, using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20for%20x%20if%20%28d%2Fdx%20%28%28x%2B1%29%2Fx%20%2B%20%282x%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%5E%28ln%286%2F5%29%2Fln%2831%2F25%29%29%29%20%3D%200%29)) gives the approximate solution
$$x \approx 3.89605$$
and a message that **Standard computation time (has been) exceeded**.

Evaluating $p(x)$ at successively larger powers of $10$ (still using WolframAlpha), starting from $x=10$, I obtain the following:
$$p(10) > 0$$
[WolframAlpha computation for $p(10)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Evaluate%20-%28%28x%2B1%29%2Fx%5E2%29%20%2B%20%281%2Fx%29%20%2B%20%28%28%281%2F%28x%2B1%29%20-%20%28x%2F%28x%2B1%29%5E2%29%29%282%5E%28ln%286%2F5%29%2Fln%2831%2F25%29%29%29%28ln%286%2F5%29%29%28x%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%5E%28%28ln%286%2F5%29%2Fln%2831%2F25%29%29-1%29%29%2F%28ln%2831%2F25%29%29%29%20at%20x%20%3D%2010)
$$p(100)  > 0$$
[WolframAlpha computation for $p(100)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Evaluate%20-%28%28x%2B1%29%2Fx%5E2%29%20%2B%20%281%2Fx%29%20%2B%20%28%28%281%2F%28x%2B1%29%20-%20%28x%2F%28x%2B1%29%5E2%29%29%282%5E%28ln%286%2F5%29%2Fln%2831%2F25%29%29%29%28ln%286%2F5%29%29%28x%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%5E%28%28ln%286%2F5%29%2Fln%2831%2F25%29%29-1%29%29%2F%28ln%2831%2F25%29%29%29%20at%20x%20%3D%20100)
$$p(1000) > 0$$
[WolframAlpha computation for $p(1000)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Evaluate%20-%28%28x%2B1%29%2Fx%5E2%29%20%2B%20%281%2Fx%29%20%2B%20%28%28%281%2F%28x%2B1%29%20-%20%28x%2F%28x%2B1%29%5E2%29%29%282%5E%28ln%286%2F5%29%2Fln%2831%2F25%29%29%29%28ln%286%2F5%29%29%28x%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%5E%28%28ln%286%2F5%29%2Fln%2831%2F25%29%29-1%29%29%2F%28ln%2831%2F25%29%29%29%20at%20x%20%3D%201000)
$$p(10000) > 0$$
[WolframAlpha computation for $p(10000)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Evaluate%20-%28%28x%2B1%29%2Fx%5E2%29%20%2B%20%281%2Fx%29%20%2B%20%28%28%281%2F%28x%2B1%29%20-%20%28x%2F%28x%2B1%29%5E2%29%29%282%5E%28ln%286%2F5%29%2Fln%2831%2F25%29%29%29%28ln%286%2F5%29%29%28x%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%5E%28%28ln%286%2F5%29%2Fln%2831%2F25%29%29-1%29%29%2F%28ln%2831%2F25%29%29%29%20at%20x%20%3D%2010000)

However, when I try to plug in, say, $x = {10}^{500} + 1$ for $p(x)$ in WolframAlpha, it returns a **Standard computation time exceeded** message.

I was wondering whether it would be possible to prove that $p(x) > 0, \forall x > {10}^{500}$?  I hope somebody with more computational power can help out with this one.

Comment: Your derivative is a plain derivative. No need to use adjective "partial".

Comment: @JeanMarie:  Thank you for your comment.  Done editing the question to omit the adjective "partial".

Comment: For finding $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}p(x)$ consider (from the your first link WA output) "Series expansion at $x=\infty$". There is a $4$-floor fraction divided by $x^2$. You need the fraction sign.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin:  I am not seeing the "Series expansion at $x = \infty$" in the first hyperlinked WA output.

Comment: $((2\^(\log(6/5)/\log(31/25)) \log(6/5))/\log(31/25) - 1)/x^2 + O((1/x)^3)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a matter of computational power.

Consider your function as a composition :

$$f(u)=u+\left(\frac{2}{u}\right)^{\alpha}$$

$$\text{with} \ u:=\frac{x+1}{x}=1+\frac{1}{x}\tag{1}$$

where $\alpha\approx 0.84757$.

Observe that the range of $u$ is interval $[1,2]$.

then write the derivative in the following way :

$$f'(u(x)).u'(x)=...$$

Computations (you have done) give

$$u'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}<0 \ \text{and} \  f'(u)=1-K\tfrac{1}{u^{\alpha+1}}$$

(with $K=\alpha 2^{\alpha} \approx 1.52517$)

As $x \to \infty, \ u \to 1_+$, therefore $f'(u)$ becomes negative for all $u<u_0=1/K^{\alpha+1}\approx 0.458466$.

The monotonicity of the inverse function $x=\frac{1}{u-1}$ (see (1)) gives the existence of $x_0:=\frac{1}{u_0-1}\approx 1.846607$ such that $x>x_0 \implies f'(u)<0$.

Therefore, we have, for $x>x_0$, a positive result (product of two negative quantities $f'(u)$ and $u'(x)$).

Comment: +1, very clever

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @JeanMarie.  I obtain
$$f'(u) = \frac{d}{du}\bigg(u + (\frac{2}{u})^{\frac{\ln(6/5)}{\ln(31/25)}}\bigg) = 1 - \frac{2^{\frac{\ln(6/5)}{\ln(31/25)}} \ln(\frac{6}{5}) \bigg(\frac{1}{u}\bigg)^{1+\frac{\ln(6/5)}{\ln(31/25)}}}{\ln(\frac{31}{25})},$$
and
$$u'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\bigg(\frac{x+1}{x}\bigg)=-\frac{1}{x^2}.$$

Comment: You are right. I am going to give an Edit to my answer.

Comment: Now I need the sign of
$$f'(u(x))\cdot{u'(x)}$$
when $x > {10}^{500}$.

But for $x > {10}^{500}$:
$$f'(u(x)) \approx 1 - \frac{2^{\frac{\ln(6/5)}{\ln(31/25)}} \ln(6/5) \bigg(1\bigg)^{1+\frac{\ln(6/5)}{\ln(31/25)}}}{\ln(31/25)} \approx -0.525 < 0$$
and evidently
$$u'(x) < 0.$$

I therefore conclude that
$$f'(u(x))u'(x) > 0$$
for $x > {10}^{500}$.

Comment: Thanks again, @JeanMarie!  +1 and accept.  =)

Answer (score 0):

Define $a = \frac{\ln(6/5)}{\ln(31/25)} \approx 0.847$ and let
$$
f(x)
 = \frac{x+1}{x}+\left(\frac{2x}{x+1}\right)^a
 = 1 + \frac1x + 2^a \left(1 - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)^a.
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{split}
f'(x)
 &= -\frac{1}{x^2} + a 2^a \left(1 - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)^{a-1}
                    \frac{d}{dx} \left[1 - \frac{1}{x+1}\right] \\
 &= -\frac{1}{x^2} + a 2^a \left(1 - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)^{a-1} \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}
\end{split}
$$
Can you finish?